# jQuery "next page" and "@name"

Tags: jquery, redirect, html

```
if ($("input[@name='questions']:checked").val() == 'a') {

        var mgoed = ['Correct! :-)', 'Goedzo, dat was het juiste antwoord!', 'Goed gedaan! :-)'];
        var goed = mgoed[Math.floor(Math.random() * mgoed.length)];
        alert(goed)
```

## Next page

I made a quiz on codiqa, if the answer is right it shows an alert with "That was right". If it's wrong it shows an alert that it's wrong.

If the answer is right, I want it to go to the next page with maybe a calculator, pages are called *#page5*, *#page6* and so on.. How can I add a +1 to the page, so that it goes from "#page4" to "#page4+1" = "page5"?

## @Name

Another small question as I couldn't find it on Google, why do I have to add a "@" to

```
 [@name='questions']
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to use `@name` unless you're using a _really old_ version of jQuery. According to [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/), that feature was removed in jQuery 1.3.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it's really old version then, otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: that convention ended about 8 years ago.